# Unixtimestamp в Datetime

Tags: c#, unixtimestamp

Есть время `1538122139000`. Хочу его сконвертировать в `DateTime`. На SO нашел множество сниппетов, но они выдают неправильное число. Скорее всего из-за длины времени. Оно тут какое-то нестандартное.

```
DateTimeOffset date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1538122139000);
```

Данный код выдаёт ошибку

```
Допустимыми являются значения в диапазоне от -62135596800 до 253402300799 включительно.
```

Comment: Откуда вы получили это число и почему считаете, что вам дают неправильный результат? А какой правильный?

Comment: Числа такой длины - это миллисекунды, вы же пытаетесь использовать `FromUnixTimeSeconds` (секунды). Попробуйте использовать `FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где то так

```
    class UnixTime
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) => Console
            .WriteLine("Test: {0}", 
                       UnixTimeToDateTime()
                       .UtcDateTime);

        private static DateTimeOffset UnixTimeToDateTime() => DateTimeOffset
            .FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1538122139000);
    }
```

Ошибка возникала и за того что был взята функция FromUnixTimeSeconds, а нужна функция FromUnixTimeMilliseconds!

Правка:

```
    class UnixTime
    {
        static Int64 _unixTime = 1538122139000;

        public static void Main(string[] args) => Console
            .WriteLine("Test: {0}", 
                       UnixTimeToDateTime(_unixTime)
                       .UtcDateTime);

        private static DateTimeOffset UnixTimeToDateTime(Int64 unixTime) => DateTimeOffset
            .FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(unixTime);
    }
```

Comment: Вы бы объяснения привели, что это, почему так, как решить проблему автора, что за ошибка у автора и почему она возникает. Ведь это будут читать разные люди, с разными знаниями, не каждый поймет просто так код! К тому же, очень много лишнего кода, вам так не кажется? Зачем нам знать, что у вас есть класс `TestClass`, метод `Main`, да и `using System;` как по мне лишнее. В общем, доработаете - плюсану ваш ответ!

Comment: Кстати, а в чем смысл метода `UnixTimeStampToDateTimeForOld()`? Сижу вот, думаю, пробую, получаю `2067.06.25 04:17:58` и недоумеваю, зачем? Может это некая "проба пера" и вы так тестировали что то у себя, тогда опять же, зачем **нам** это?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ,  спонтанный ответ) редактирую

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, не разбирался!)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, исправил!

Comment: И как вам ответ? Нравится? Мне как то не очень. Вы взяли, сжали код, не убрав лишнего, зачем то его продублировали с пометкой "правка", да еще и описания почти не какого. Вот если у вас ошибка в задание, вы спросите у меня помощь, а я вам отвечу "Ты используешь красную ручку, а надо синюю!", вам даст это хоть какую то полезную информацию? Тут примерно тоже самое. Хочу кстати заметить, что в C# "функция" это совсем другое понятие и принято говорить "метод". Вообще, если вы говорите про `FromUnixTime*` методы, то вполне достаточно написать одну строку (как у автора вопроса) и пояснить почему так

Comment: @ EvgeniyZ, в полне норм